# Xcode Bot Stuck Building Sources While Integrating

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, codesign, xcode-bots

[image]

Xcode integration sticks while making ".ipa" for bundle sources on signing product. Have been stuck for many hours. :(

i am working on automated testflight builds with xcode-bots,While integrating ,bots get hang up at bundle sources as shown in image,I have put my certificates and provisioning profile in Xcode-Server keychain and provisioning profile folder respectively,Still getting error.

Any help would be appreciated..:)

Comment: You will have to try and provide us with more information

Comment: @unicorn2 please check out the edit, and let me know if you need more information

Comment: Hi,Is there any solution for this,am stuck for past 2 days...:(

Comment: @Diksha  even i am facing the same issue for one project, got the solution ?

Comment: @user yes by adding certificates system/library folder.But I would suggest you to do the build automation and integration with "fastlane".It is a good tool.